# Export and compare properties of expression in vba

Tags: vba, checkbox, getelementsbyclassname

The overview in "Watches" in the vba editor of office 2016 seemed not clear/easily comparable, so I would like to export the expressions under "Watches".

Because I have a manual "watch" on the only `item` in `elements1a` and I would like to be able to export all the properties (I think they are called "expressions", but I have not found the correct naming yet).

So that I can compare the properties(every dropdown possiblility/expression such as: "checked", "innerText" etc. ) of the `item` with itself after a manipulation of the `item`.

1. It seemed slightly confusing that the "sub-expressions of expressions are also called expressions.
2. I foresee a problem since you can click a "sub-expression of a parent expression, and in that sub-expression click "parent expression of sub-expression again" Effectively creating an infinite expression loop.

Hence I doubt whether it is possible at al.

Comment: Instead of hacking your way through the implementation of the page, you should try to simulate the behavior of a real user. Something like: `If Not Item.Checked Then Item.Click`.

Comment: Thank you, I believe I am trying to simulate the behavior of a real user. So after 2 attempts lucky guesses, I switched to trying to find out what the real user does by inspecting the changes in the expressions of the item that the user clicks. Yet a more structured approach will aid in my learning. Thank you!

Comment: some are objects, some are properties of objects   .... this explains some .... http://www.excel-spreadsheet.com/vba/objecthierarchy.htm  .... if you want to compare two properties at runtime then use `debug.print`